# Redirecting through a very stubborn htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Hi and thanks for trying (and probably succeeding more than me) and solving this *slight* issue.

I'm trying to permanently redirect an URL in an htaccess that was written by my predecessors for an online store made using Prestashop.

Currently, the important bits of the htaccess look like this:

```
    RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/catalogue/]
RewriteRule ^api/?(.*)$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^poemana.com$      
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.poemana.com/catalogue/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.poemana.com$      
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.poemana.com/catalogue/$1 [R=301,L]
```

From what I can tell, everything redirects forcefully to  /catalogue/ , and is then taken care of by an internal dispatcher.
I don't mind that, it does its job just fine. In fact, my SEO would take a massive hit if it were changed.

What I need and can't get to work is an exception to the rewritebase.
Specifically, I need the following URL:

```
https://poemana.com/.well-known/pki-validation/B7C70F58C2447665A564636085D84883.txt
```

to be unaffected.
Currently, it's being forced to:

```
https://poemana.com/catalogue/.well-known/pki-validation/B7C70F58C2447665A564636085D84883.txt
```

I would be extremely grateful if I had a solution, as it's for an SSL certificate, and my hosting service has given me 7 days to get it fixed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My current attempts as seen below to add a RewriteCond just above the RewriteBase does nothing.

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/.well-known`

Comment: Through a combination of rewriteconds and rewriterules, I did manage earlier to rewrite every URL so it loads the correct .txt page, while still showing up under a /catalogue path.

It would almost had been comical had it not been the middle of the night and were I not on a deadline.

Comment: Someone tried to help, and the solution of adding: RewriteRule \.well-known - [L]  right before the RewriteEngine On doesn't work either. Did I lie or not when I said that the htaccess was stubborn?

Answer (score 0):

After trial and error with someone from another website, we figured out that inserting:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.well-know
```

Above every single RewriteRule solved the problem.

The magic of htaccess has been once again tamed.